# Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ id: '5f1c64aa177bf9379491ecc8' }" at path "_id" for model "User"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs, mongoose-schema

I'am trying to make simple todoapp with Nestjs.
I have two module one is User and Task. Task module works just fine i can add new task, findbyId method works fine.I can add new User but when i've tried to findbyId in user model this happen `{"statusCode":500,"message":"Internal server error"}` error.

user.schema.ts:

```js
export const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({  
    email: {type:String},
    nickname:{type:String, required:[true, 'Nickname is required']},
    password:{type:String, required:[true, 'Password is required']},
    tasks: { type:Array },
    updateAt:{type:Date, default:Date.now},  
})
```

user.service.ts:

```js
async getOne(id:string): Promise<User>{
    return await this.userModel.findById(id).exec();
    }
```

task.schema.ts

```js
export const TaskSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: { type:String, required:true},
    user: {type:String ,required:true},
    description: {type:String, required:false},
    category: {type:String,required:true},
    updateAt:{type:Date, default:Date.now}
})
```

task.service.ts

```js
async getOne(id: string): Promise <Task>{
    return await this.taskModel.findById(id).exec();
}
```

Thank you for your time !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your `id` value in the `getOne` method is not actually a string, but rather an Object containing:

`{ id: '5f1c64aa177bf9379491ecc8' }`

So you could change this to call `findById` with the actual `id`:

```
async getOne(idHolder: any): Promise <Task>{

    return await this.taskModel.findById(idHolder.id).exec();
}
```

Comment: After i've send the question i realised that i didn't pass the id  in my user.controller.ts
like this 
@Get(':id') 
    getOne(@Param('id') id: string) {

        return this.userService.getOne(id);
    }
but thanks for your answer it works too !